# For the set of all Injective functions $f: X \to Y$, does $|X|=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I was given the following problem worded exactly:

> "Let $X,Y \neq \emptyset$ and suppose that every element of $F(X,Y)$ is injective. Show that $|X|=1.$"

and the set  $F(X,Y) := \{f\ | f:X \to Y \} $

I can't prove this statement holds, *in fact I think it is false*. I came up with the following argument:

Suppose that every element of $F(X,Y)$ is injective, and modifying the definition above we get the set $$F(X,Y) := \{f\ | f:X \to Y \ \wedge f(x_1)=f(x_2)\ \supset \ \ x_1=x_2\} $$

Take set $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ and set $Y=\{y_1,y_2,\dots,y_m\}$ $n\le m$

and we can construct a counterexample where $f_1$ is injective and maps $x_i\to y_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$.

Or similarly lets say $f_2$ is injective and maps $x_i\to y_{2i}$ for all $i=1,...,n$ where $y_{2i}\le m$.

This would mean $|X|\neq1$.

However I can see that if $|X|=1$ and $Y$ was nonempty then necessarily  $f:X \to Y$ would be injective.

*Can you help explain if I'm wrong, how I am wrong and what the proof would be that shows the statement above holds?* Thanks.

Comment: I think you're mixing up "every function from $X$ to $Y$ is injective" and "there exists a function $f: X \to Y$ that's injective."

Comment: @pjs36 That was the wording I was given the problem in. It says evey element of the set $F(X,Y)$ which are functions.

Comment: The hypothesis is that there does NOT exist a non-injective $f:X\to Y.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that the existence of **some** injective functions $f\colon X \to Y$ doesn't disprove the claim that "if **all** functions $f \colon X \to Y$ are injective then $|X| = 1$." Indeed, by assuming $|X| \le |Y|$, there are injective functions from $X$ to $Y$, yet the claim is still true.

Instead of using contradiction, to prove that

$$\text{If every function in $F(X, Y)$ is injective, then $|X| = 1$}$$ it's much easier to prove the contrapositive:

$$\text{If $|X| > 1$, then there exists some function $f \in F(X, Y)$ that's not injective}$$

(we're assuming $X, Y$ are nonempty, so the negation of $|X| = 1$, that is $|X| \neq 1$, amounts to $|X| > 1$).

I think you'll have a much easier time believing this is true, and even proving it. Just pick some generic sets $X, Y$ with $|X| > 1$ and see if you can find a way to build a function that isn't injective. Before long you'll have some ideas about how to prove it for general $X, Y$.

Comment: Nice explanation! I might remark that one doesn't need contradiction to prove the original implication. Indeed, if every function $X \to Y$ is injective and $X, Y$ are nonempty, then the constant function $f_{y} \colon X \to Y$ which sends every $x \in X$ to some fixed $y \in Y$ is injective.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you, and your alternative is very slick, it definitely didn't occur to me!

Comment: @AlexWertheim Can you please explain how the statement about the constant function proves the statement? Because I don't understand intuitively why that would allow us to exclude other injective functions from $F$ where the $|X| \neq1$... even a hint would be helpful thanks!!

Comment: @Red: for any $x, x' \in X$, $f_{y}(x) = f_{y}(x') = y$. Since *every* function from $X$ to $Y$ is injective by hypothesis, $f_{y}$ must be injective, so $f_{y}(x) = f_{y}(x')$ implies $x = x'$. Since $x, x'$ were arbitrary elements of $X$, this shows that all elements of $X$ must be equal, i.e. $X$ has one element.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b\in X$ with $a\ne b$ then for any $c\in Y$ the function $X\times \{c\}$ is not injective.

Note: You might call $X\times  \{c\}$ the graph of a function. In set theory, a function IS its graph.